# response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;' in django not downloading the file

Tags: javascript, python, django

```
filename = "/filepath/in/server"
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='application/octet-stream')
        response['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename'
        print response
        return response
```

Clicking on button in my web application should download and save the file from server to my desktop. My html code contains only the button and onclick function(which submits the form and invokes POST). The Post script is written in views.py. The above code is also written in views.py but clicking on the  button doesn't download the file as attachment. I can see response content printed in server side.

EDIT: the HTML code

```
<form id="downloadFile" name="downloadFile" method="post"> 
  <button id="downloadbtn" name="downloadbtn" onclick="downloadFile(this);"></button>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken17" value="{{ csrf_token }}"/>
  <input id="downloadForm" type="hidden" name="form_type" value="downloadVCMTSRules"/>
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadFile(activeElement){ 
       document.getElementById("downloadFile").method="POST"; 
       document.getElementById("downloadFile").submit();
    }
</script>
```

If i click the button the page just reloads.

Comment: Please post the html code and the full view code (FWIW you don't need any js to submit a form). And if you're only serving a file, it should be a GET request, not a POST (unless the process also imply modifying your server's state). Also what happens when you click the button ? You say it's not downloaded but you don't explain what happens instead.

Comment: <form id="downloadFile" name="downloadFile" method="post"> <button id="downloadbtn" name="downloadbtn" onclick="downloadFile(this);"></button>{% csrf_token %}<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken17" value="{{ csrf_token }}"/><input id="downloadForm" type="hidden" name="form_type" value="downloadVCMTSRules"/></form>
Javascript
function downloadFile(activeElement){
     document.getElementById("downloadFile").method="POST";
     document.getElementById("downloadFile").submit();}
If i click the button the page just reloads.

Comment: next time please update your question - code in comments is barely readable.

Comment: First remove the onclick handler and add `type="submit"` to your button. If that doesn't fix the problem, then post the whole view code (_please_ edit your question, don't post it as a comment)

Comment: The views code is big cause there are many functions like upload, save, delete actions. Kindly help me with the code cause i'm really stuck.

Comment: then reduce your view code to the minimum required to reproduce the problem (make _sure_ it does reproduce the problem). No one can debug code without seeing it. But first try why I told in my previous comment: remove the js part and make sure your code works (or doesn't) without it. I doubt the problem is with the js part actually but the only way to know for sure is to try without.

Comment: Tried to remove the onclick event. Still the file is not getting downloaded.

Comment: Then (assuming the symptom is still the same - page refreshes instead) the problem is vbery probably in the part of the view you didn't post, and no one can help you without seeing that code. Hint : add a new view that only handles this exact part of the code and post your form to this new view's url. This should make clear whether there's a bug in your original 800-pounds-gorilla view (which is probably doing way to many things from what you describe) or the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked :) It was because of the class view it got stuck with the httpresponse.